# How to check user and password authentication

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an application with angularJS and php on backend ,I want to implement authentication in my application, and I tried the code pasted below, but it doesn't generates any error, any message and when I try to put a username and password I go to the view'admin"whatever the user I enter, it means that it doesn't check the user and password. In the database of table 'client', I have : NomClient and mdp(password).

login.html

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
<div class="list list-inset" >
<label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="nom" required="" ng-model="NomClient"> 
</label> 
<label class="item item-input">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="mdp"> 
</label> 
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>       
 </ion-content>
```

app.js

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope,$state,$http){
  $scope.submit= function(){
 const url = 'http://localhost/deb/login.php';
const postBody = {
    NomClient: $scope.NomClient,
    mdp: $scope.mdp
};

$http.post(url, postBody).then(data => {
   $location.path('/admin');
});
};
```

login.php

```
 <?php  

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tem");  


$response['status'] = 0;
$response['message'] = '';
$NomClient=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->NomClient);
$mdp=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->mdp);


$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE NomClient = "'.$NomClient.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'"';


if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    $response['status'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    echo jsone_encode($response);exit;
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rowcount>0){
    $response['status'] = 1;
    $response['message'] = 'Login successful';
}
else{
    $response['status'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid username of password';
}

echo json_encode($response);exit;
 ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

OK. You have a number of issues here. To start with, you should be using prepared statements for the query.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT * FROM client WHERE NomClient = ? AND   mdp=?;");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss', $NomClient, $mdp);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
$rowcount = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)
mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

The bigger issue is that you are storing the password in the clear and this is a horrible, horrible way to do password management. Please look into password_hash() and password_verify().